# Why is this piece of java code giving me so many errors?

Tags: java

The following is giving me a lot of errors within console, which don't show up if `screen S` is initialized with `new screen(10)`(you should decrease the array size beforehand), why is this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class screen{
    JFrame window=new JFrame();
    JPanel scr=new JPanel();
    JPanel[][] pixels=new JPanel[240][360];
    screen(int scale){
        scr.setLayout(new GridLayout(240,360));
        int x=0;
        for(JPanel Fx[]:pixels){
        for(JPanel Fy:Fx){
            Fy=new JPanel();
            if(x%3==0){Fy.setBackground(Color.red);}
            if(x%3==1){Fy.setBackground(Color.green);}
            if(x%3==2){Fy.setBackground(Color.blue);}
            x++;
            Fy.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(scale,scale));
            scr.add(Fy);}}
        window.add(scr);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.pack();
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args){
        screen S=new screen(1);
    }
}
```

Edit (since I can't reply due to lack of karma):

@Makoto:

This is the errors I'm getting,

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O28f0.png]

@Hovercraft Full Of Eels:

I've changed the for loops to iterate ints, but it gives me the same errors.

Comment: @PradeepSimha:  Look again.  There are methods.  The code is in the methods.  It's just not immediately apparent.

Comment: There's nothing syntatically wrong with your code.  Do you have some error message you're getting?  It's tough to understand what you're talking about from this alone.

Comment: @Makoto: there's a logic error in his creating a new JPanel and assigning it to the for-each variable.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need so many `JPanel`?
You create `JPanel` `86400` times (`240x360`).

Answer (score 0):

- Note that you cannot create objects in a for-each loop. Instead use a regular for loop. The reason is the for-each loop hides its actual true structure, and the true structure does not allow for new object creation and assignment, because of the use of an "invisible" iterator, the inner loop variable, in your loop, Fy, is a temporary variable, and you cannot assign a new object to it and assume that it will be assigned to the array. In otherwords this: `Fy=new JPanel();` does *not* assign a new JPanel to the array but rather to a temporary variable. The only way to assign to the array is to use a standard for loop.
- You should never have that many errors, and having them suggests that your code style is wrong. If you aren't allowed to use an advanced IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse, then you should compile your code early and often, and you should not add any new code until all current code compiles without error.
- Consider using a JTable instead of a huge grid that you're using.